# How to ingore "Text size is too small"

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I ignore the "Text size is too small" warning in Android Studio?

For example, in one of my TextViews:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:text="@string/navtask_btn_arrived"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="8sp"
    tools:ignore="textSize"/>
```

I tried to add:

```
tools:ignore="textSize"

tools:ignore="TextSize"

tools:ignore="SpUsage"

tools:ignore="spUsage"

tools:ignore="dimen"
```

It is supposed to work with "textSize", as the documentation mentions it can be used with any attribute.

I know some of these do not make any sense, but hey, why not try them out before asking here?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add attribute `tools:ignore="SmallSp"` to remove the warning use `SmallSp` where `SmallSp` mean small scalable pixels as

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:text="@string/navtask_btn_arrived"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="8sp"
    tools:ignore="SmallSp"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Android Studio gives error:**

*Avoid using sizes smaller then 12sp.So try to avoid using below 12sp size.
If you still want to use then declare below the line.*

```
tools:ignore="SmallSp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Minimum text size is 12sp in android

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:text="@string/navtask_btn_arrived"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    tools:ignore="textSize"/>
```

Comment: You can use smaller sizes if you want. 12sp is just the minimum recomended size.